How to split a hex string into individual bytes?
I am trying to split a hexadecimal string, 3E8.8F5C28F5C28, into individual bytes. I tried the following code to split the string:
const string = "3E8.8F5C28F5C28";
const res = string.split(/([\d\w]{2})/).filter(e => e);

But it gave me this result:
[
  '3E', '8.', '8F',
  '5C', '28', 'F5',
  'C2', '8'
]

I need to split the given hex string like 03 E8 8F. I don't want the fractional values after 8F.
How to achieve this?

What is the logic behind this splitting?

i am receiving a sensor data as hexadecimal fractional value like 3E8.8F5C28F5C28. but the fractional part is too big to parse so i need only first two digits of fractional value and the integer part. I am sending this value in a packet which can hold only three bytes for the information part which can send the value like 03 MSB , E8 middle byte and 8F as lower byte.

You could first pad the string so it has an even number of hex digits in both the integer as fractional parts. Then clip the fractional part to just 2 digits, and finally match all digit pairs.


const string = "3E8.8F5C28F5C28";
const res = string
     .replace(/^(\w\w)*\w\b/, "0$&") // Pad integer part  
     .replace(/\b(\w\w)*\w$/, "$&0") // Pad fractional part
     .replace(/(\.\w\w).*/, "$1")    // Keep at most 2 decimals
     .match(/\w\w/g);                // Get hex pairs
     
console.log(res);



Explanation
The first replace call has a regex that matches an odd number of hex digits from the start (^) and until it hits a word-break (\b; either because it is the end of the string, or there is a decimal point). The (\w\w)* pattern matches as many pairs as possible, and then the following \w matches one more digit, making it an odd number. In the replace string, $& represents what was matched, so 0$& adds a zero before the part that was matched, so at the start.
The second replace call is very similar: it also matches an odd number of digits: after the previous one, that could only concern the part after the decimal point. Here the replacement string adds the zero after what was matched, so at the very end.
The third replace finds the first two digits after the decimal point, puts them in a capture group together with the decimal point, and matches any trailing characters. The replacement only repeats the capture group, so that the trailing characters are effectively removed.
The final match call matches any pair of digits. Since we had ensured that the integer part has an even number of digits, this captures all of them as pairs. The decimal part (if any) has two digits, so those two will also be matched.

Added an explanation section. Thanks!

Thanks for your reply the explanation part is very helpful to understand.

It's an easy task do it like this:
const string = "3E8.8F5C28F5C28";
// Remove the fractional part
const sanitizedString = string.split(".")[0];
const result = sanitizedString.padStart(sanitizedString.length + (sanitizedString.length % 2), '0').match(/.{1,2}/g) || [];
console.log(result);


Yasin thanks for your reply, but i need the data 8F after fractional point if i use split(".") i cant able to get the data after fractional point

@VijayakumarSargunam in your question, it seems to me you ask the opposite "I don't want the fractional values after 8F"
